# sending commands/values between pages

Tags: javascript, html

im working on a website with 2 pages 1 is the receiver and 2 is the remote basicly you can enter a text on page 2 and once you hit submit page1 starts playing a text to speatch message with the text inut from page2

index.html (aka : page1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="header"></h1>

    <script src="src/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

control.html (aka : page2)

```
<body>
<center>
<form>
<h1 style="color:green">Javatpoint</h1>
<h3> Confirm password Validation Example </h3>
<!-- Enter Password -->
<td> Enter Password </td>
<input type = "password" name = "pswd1"> <br><br>
<button type = "submit" onclick="matchPassword()">Submit</button>
<script>
var pw1 = document.getElementById("pswd1");
function matchPassword() {
  <script src="script.js"><script> var x1
}
</script>
```

script.js of page1

```
const message = 'Hello world' // Try edit me

// Update header text
document.querySelector('#header').innerHTML = message

// Log to console
console.log(message)
var audio = new Audio('notif.mp3');
audio.play();
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
msg.text = "hallo jeremy";
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

i cant find a way to send the text inside page2 to page 1

Comment: In page 2 you have a script tag inside your script tag. What is that trying to do?
Is the login purely done in JavaScript?

Comment: at page 2 its may posible to just use promopt() insthead of the password bar

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways that you could achieve this, but I'll show you just one. You can easily pass data between pages using [query parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), which are essentially pieces of data appended to the end of a URL.

In order to utilize these, you would need to redirect to your `index.html` page whenever the user presses the button in the `control.html` page. Fortunately, this can be done by adding an event listener to your Submit button.

Here is the code below:

**control.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <p>Enter stuff here:</p>
      <input type="text" id="text-input" name="text" />
      <input type="submit" id="submit-button"></input>
    </form>
    <!-- continue document... -->
    <script src="src/control.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**src/script.js**

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

const message = queryParams.get("text");

console.log(message);

// continue file...
```

**src/control.js**

```
const button = document.getElementById("submit-button");
button.addEventListener("click", handleText);

function handleText(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const text = document.getElementById("text-input").value;
  const currentURL = window.location.pathname;
  const currentDir = currentURL.substring(0, currentURL.lastIndexOf("/"));

  window.location.replace(currentDir + "/index.html?text=" + text);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it dident work but thanks for the help anyway :D